# Clear inputs. Specific fields

Tags: jquery

```
$(':input','#myform')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
  .val('')
  .removeAttr('checked')
  .removeAttr('selected');
```

How to use it only for specific fields ID, not for all input in my form?

```
<input type="text" name="example" id="id_example"/>
<input type="text" name="example1" id="id_example1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) with [ID Selector (“#id”)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$(':input#id_example, :input#id_example1','#myform')
```

The ids are supposed to be **unique** you can just use ids

```
$('#id_example, #id_example1','#myform')
```

> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single
>   result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to
>   select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order, [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

So just use the id selector, and use `.val('')` to remove the input for input text.

```
$('#id_example,#id_example1').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':input#id','#myform')
.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
.val('')
.removeAttr('checked')
.removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'starts with' selector too:

```
$('#myform').find('[id^=id_example]').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

`:input` selects all the form elements whether that is a `input[type=text], input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset] etc. or select, textarea etc.`

Try this:

```
$('#myform').find(':text').val('').addBack(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

this clears the values of all the text inputs and unchecks the checkboxes.